# Finding the Limit of a Function with Radicals and Fraction

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{2}}{x}$

That is the full problem. This was my attempt at simplifying and solving it.

$\lim_{x\to 0} x(\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{2})$

$0(\sqrt{0+2}-\sqrt{2})=0$

Using a graphing calculator, I determined that the answer should be around 0.35, so my answer is incorrect. I'm fairly certain that I simplified it incorrectly, but I'm not sure the proper way. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can't just move that $x$ from the denominator to the numerator! Why would you do that?

Comment: @MikePierce Yeah you're right. It's been awhile and I switched up a few things, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{2}}{x}=\dfrac{d(\sqrt{x+2})}{dx}_{\text{at }x=2}$$

---

OR

Let $\sqrt{x+2}=u\implies x=u^2-2$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{2}}{x}=\lim_{u\to\sqrt2}\dfrac{u-\sqrt2}{u^2-2}=\lim_{u\to\sqrt2}\dfrac1{u+\sqrt2}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply your function with $\frac{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{2}}=1$, notice the similarity/difference to the original numerator and after applying $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ you will see some terms cancel, leading you to a solvable limit.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way $$ A={\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}\,\Big(\sqrt{1+\frac x 2}-1\Big)$$ You probably know that, when $y$ is small $\sqrt{1+y}\approx 1+\frac y2$. Replace $y$ by $\frac x2$; this makes $$A\approx \sqrt{2}\,\Big(1+\frac x 4-1\Big)=\frac {\sqrt{2}} 4 x$$